# NodeJS : what is require modules best practices?

Tags: javascript, node.js

currently I've created a NodeJS project following below structures:

```
   /(root)
   ----> controller
       ----> aController.js
   ----> model
   ----> module
       ----> aModule.js
   ----> util
       ----> util.js
   app.js
```

The problem is example, in `controller/aController.js` I use the module fs, so I do `fs = require('fs')` to include the `fs` module.

The problem is in `module/aModule.js` I also want to use the fs, if I do another `fs=require('fs')` is it correct with "Node.js way"?

Same issue with above, I want to `require('util/util.js')` in both Modules and Controllers also. What's the best practice in this case?

Comment: See related question/answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26694961/the-fundamentals-of-the-node-js-module-paradigm/26695038#26695038

Comment: thanks for recommend me that @jfriend00 ! I'll read it carefully!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do `var fs = require("fs")` (or `var myLib = require("path/to/my/lib")`) so many times you need (in different files).

`require` has an internal cache (`require.cache`), so same memory will be used.

From documentation:

> ### [`require.cache`](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_require_cache)
>
> Modules are cached in this object when they are required. By deleting a key value from this object, the next require will reload the module.

---

### Example

Having the following files:

```
.
├── a.js
├── b.js
└── u.js
```

#### `u.js`

```
this.say = "Hello World!";
```

#### `a.js`

```
var u = require("./u");
u.say = "Hello Mars!"; // change `say` property value
require("./b");        // load b.js file
```

#### `b.js`

```
console.log(require("./u").say); // output `say` property
```

Output: `"Hello Mars!"`. **Why?** Because `u.js` loaded from `b.js` is loaded from `require.cache` (where `u.say` is set to `"Hello Mars!"` by `a.js`).

To prevent loading from cache you can remove files from `require.cache` using `delete require.cache[<absolute-path-to-file>]`. Let's change `b.js` content as follows:

```
 delete require.cache[require.resolve("./u")];
 console.log(require("./u").say); // output `say` property
```

Output: `"Hello World!"` because the file wasn't loaded from cache but from disk.

Comment: Thanks for show me that! So, The duplicate `require` is acceptable, isn't it?

Comment: @JhKaiz You're welcome. Sure, because that's the way how require works. That's one of the reasons it has cache object.

Comment: Thanks, I'll remember it. Edit : for example, in `util.js` I have `this.say ="hello"`, in `aController` I set it `util.say = "goodbye"`, so in `bController` which also require `util`, what will be displayed if I call a function like `function sayWhat() { console.log(util.say)}` ??

Comment: @Ionica please check my comment above.

Comment: @JhKaiz `"goodbye"` because modules aren't loaded multiple times from disk unless you delete them from `require.cache` -- see edit.